# Wrong text rendering in Qml when using unicode characters

Tags: qt, unicode, fonts, qml, rendering

Text is rendered wrong when using unicode characters.

In 1st grid is the text as is should be.

In 2nd grid inserted `⭐` character.

In 3rd grid I created a dummy Text

`text: t2.text`

and calculated the Test2 pixel size

`font.pixelSize: t1.font.pixelSize * t1.height / dummy.height`

but text is rendered too small.

How do I fix this?

Example

[image]

EDIT:

```
ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
width: 400
height: 200
title: qsTr("Hello World")

Text {
    id: dummy
    visible: false
    font.bold: true
    text: t2.text
}

RowLayout {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    spacing: 40

    GridLayout {
        columns: 2
        Text {
            text: qsTr("Test1:")
        }
        Text {
            id: t1
            font.bold: true
            text: qsTr("Test2")
        }
        Text {
            text: qsTr("Test3:")
        }
        Text {
            font.bold: true
            text: qsTr("Test4")
        }
    }

    GridLayout {
        columns: 2
        Text {
            text: qsTr("Test1:")
        }
        Text {
            font.bold: true
            text: qsTr("⭐Test2")
        }
        Text {
            text: qsTr("Test3:")
        }
        Text {
            font.bold: true
            text: qsTr("Test4")
        }
    }

    GridLayout {
        columns: 2
        Text {
            text: qsTr("Test1:")
        }
        Text {
            id: t2
            font.bold: true
            text: qsTr("⭐Test2")
            font.pixelSize: t1.font.pixelSize * t1.height / dummy.height
        }
        Text {
            text: qsTr("Test3:")
        }
        Text {
            font.bold: true
            text: qsTr("Test4")
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: show your code!!

Comment: So what's your issue? The title is misleading. You are seeing the right text, it's just the sizing that's too small? 

AFAIK, copying and pasting that star character doesn't mean you are using unicode. Your file could be using some other encoding. You can specify the unicode character explicitly using "\u2B50 Text2"

I don't see this problem using Qt 5.9 on Windows 8.